# An infinite chain of theories

Tags: logic, set-theory, foundations

Let $\sf X$ be some theory stronger in some form than $\sf ZFC$.

In the theory $\sf X$, you might be able to prove $con(\sf ZFC)$

Now, let $\sf Y$ be some theory stronger in some way or form than theory $X$.

In theory $\sf Y$, you might be able to prove $con(\sf X)$

Now, let theory $\sf N$ be some theory that is somehow "infinitely more strong" than all other theories.

My question is that:

- In this case, it is possible to prove $con(\sf N)$?
- Is there a more formal way to describe this chain of theories? And if so, would the theory $\sf N$ be able to prove $con(\sf N-1)$, where $\sf N-1$ is a theory that is $1 \space unit$ less than $\sf N$, assuming we have formally defined what a "unit" is in the case?

Comment: The term is "stronger".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, where do you wish to "prove $\operatorname{Con}(\mathsf N)$"?

If you $\sf N$ satisfies the conditions of Godel's incompleteness theorem, then $\sf N$ cannot prove its own consistency. Period. End of story. On the other hand, we can show that from the assumption "There exists a transitive model of $\sf ZFC$" we can prove the consistency of $\sf ZFC+\operatorname{Con}^n(ZFC)$ for all $n$, and more. So you can find such $\sf N$ and prove its consistency all the same.

On the other hand, working in $\sf PA$, we can still talk about $\sf ZFC$ and an infinite chain of stronger theories (simply take $T_0=\sf ZFC$ and $T_{n+1}=T+\operatorname{Con}(T_n)$, then $T=\bigcup_n T_n$ is a perfectly recursive theory). But nonetheless, $\sf PA$ cannot even prove that $\sf ZFC$ is consistent, let alone any stronger theory.

So again, the issue is that proofs don't live in vacuo. Proofs are born from theories. And unless you tell us what is the theory in which you're working, we cannot tell you if you can prove the consistency of $\sf N$.

Finally, you could---and should---describe these theories as stronger in the sense that each theory *proves* the consistency of the previous one. But that's more or less all we can say here. Do note that it is possible to prove the consistency of $T$ in a theory $T'$ which is not stronger than $T$, in the sense that while $T'$ proves the consistency of $T$, it does not prove all the statements of $T$. For example, the consistency of $\sf ZFC$ can be proved from $\sf PA+\operatorname{Con}(ZFC)$. Or $\sf PA$ can be proved consistent from $\sf PRA+\operatorname{Con}(PA)$. So again, this becomes a delicate issue to consider.

Comment: So some theory $\sf A$ can be weaker than some other theory $\sf B$, and yet within theory $\sf A$, $con(\sf B)$ can be proved? This leads me to wonder, what is the minimum set of requirements that a theory must have in order to be able to prove $con(\sf some \space other \space theory)$?

Comment: Not weaker, but "incomparable". There is no reasonable criteria to give you "a minimal set of requirements". Essentially you need to be able to internalize FOL and the notion of consistency, and have Con(T) as an axiom or a theorem.

Comment: Well, Con(T) is a statement about the integers, it can be translated---or assumed---to a statement in some logic, but in essence it's a statement about the integers. Without some sufficient theory to interpret what it means for a formula defining a theory to be defining a consistent theory (namely, without the sufficient structure for interpreting first-order logic), this axiom is utterly meaningless. So you can't quite treat it as its own theory. But when we adjoin Con(T) to T, assuming T is strong enough (as is the case with ZFC) we get a stronger theory by definition.

Comment: Thanks! There's a confusing part in your main answer, though: Can we or can we not prove $con (\sf N)$?

Comment: Prove from *what assumptions*? In what theory?

Comment: Well, if we assume that theory $\sf N$ is infinitely strong, then if it satisfies Geodel's incompleteness theorems, then as you mentioned before, $\sf N$ cannot prove its own consistency. This sort of brings us to a "meta-question", can we verify that $\sf N$ indeed follows those theorems?

Comment: Sure. You started with something like PA or ZFC, and you defined N by *recursion*. So you still got a recursively enumerable theory, and you got a theory stronger than PA or ZFC (whatever you started with), so it still interprets arithmetic just fine. So if N is consistent, it cannot prove its own consistency.

Comment: So then, we can't prove $con(\sf N)$, or is it that we have limited information to even be able to decide the answer?

Comment: No, no no. We cannot prove the consistency of N ***from N itself***. We can still prove its consistency from any theory that can prove con(N). For example, PA+Con(N).

Comment: But doesn't that lead us into a sort of infinite loop? To prove "con[(PA + con(N)]", we need some theory "X + PA + con(N)", and to prove *that* theory, we need another theory, "Y + con(X) + PA + con(N)", and so on.

Comment: Yes. In conclusion, there is no reasonably strong foundation of mathematics which can prove its own consistency. There is no such thing in real life either, though. Can you *prove* without a shadow of a doubt that you're not a brain in a jar? That anyone exists other than yourself? That you're not a simulation? No. You have to take some utilitarian approach to these things and realize that either way, you're going to eventually succumb to entropy and die. Here is the same thing. At some point, you just take it on faith that some theory is consistent, and you work from there.

Comment: Yes, I can prove that I am not a brain in a jar, and there are lots of philosophical texts about this. However, back on topic, do you mean like at some point I just have to assume the consistency of a theorem as a sort of default axiom?

Comment: Eh, I don't believe you since you don't exist and those papers are clearly the figment of my imagination, and I clearly cannot trust the imagination of such a raving madman... :-) But back to the topic at hand, at some point you need to decide that some theory T is good enough to work with, and just work with that. ZFC is good enough, so even if you cannot prove Con(ZFC) from ZFC itself, we assume it's consistent, and that's something already. Many people (read: logicians) might even go beyond ZFC and include some mild-enough large cardinal axioms, and some would even include stronger ones.

Comment: Philosophers have discussed this at length and we do *not* live in any kind of vat, jar, or simulation. :D 

Back on topic,  why do you think ZFC is a bit more "popular" or "famous" than other theories?

Comment: Don't believe everything a philosopher tells you, some of them might tell you that women suffrage is bad, that human sacrifice is good, and that morality is inherent to the universe. :-) ZFC is popular and famous because it managed to do two things: (1) satisfy the needs for a set theory, when there was one, and mathematicians like von Neumann, Godel and others showed how useful it is; and (2) be flexible enough and yet strong enough to prove a myriad of results. But many mathematicians don't even know what axioms ZFC include, or anything about axiomatic set theory or foundations.

Comment: I don't believe anything and everything for no reason, I was just saying that science and philosophy can indeed prove that we ain't in any brain jars. :)

Anyways, back on topic, what do you mean by some mathematicians not knowing about ZFC? What do you mean by that?

Comment: Prove? I beg to differ. They can make reasonably convincing arguments but nothing more. :-) What I mean by that, is that many people don't even know what are the axioms of ZFC, or how it can serve as a foundation for mathematics. People are aware that it can be formalized, sometimes, but they are usually uninterested in the machinations of such formalization or what are the axioms of set theory state explicitly, why they were chosen as such, or what difficulties can arise from them and how those difficulties can be circumvented (when possible).

Comment: I beg to differ, this can be scientifically proven 100%, actually. :-)

Anyways, back on the topic at hand, thank you for your answer. I've accepted your main answer, and unless a better one comes up I might keep it that way.

Answer (score 6):

This phenomenon has been well-studied, at least for arithmetic, but the results should extend to ZFC and similar theories.

You can iterate into the transfinite the process of passing from a theory $T$ to the theory $T + \operatorname{Con}(T),$ using notations for recursive ordinals (and taking unions at the limit stages).

The construction has levels going up to (but not including) $\omega_1^{CK},$ the least non-recursive ordinal (the Church-Kleene $\omega_1).$

The whole situation is quite tricky, because the theory that corresponds to a particular notation for a recursive ordinal generally depends on the notation chosen, not just on the ordinal. (The specific issue is that at a limit stage $\lambda,$ the theory you get will depend on the particular cofinal $\omega$-sequence through $\lambda$ that you use, and on the notations chosen for the members of that $\omega$-sequence.)

Somewhat surprisingly, you can find a recursive progression of theories through Kleene's $\mathscr{O}$ (the set of all notations for recursive ordinals), together with a path through $\mathscr{O}$ that is itself recursive in $\mathscr{O},$ such that the union of the theories along this path is true first-order arithmetic.

On the other hand, there is also a wide collection of paths through $\mathscr{O}$ such that the union of theories along the path is incomplete with respect to even $\Pi^0_1$ sentences of arithmetic.

The above is all for theories of arithmetic, but I think everything should work for ZFC and similar theories as well, in terms of asking which sentences of true arithmetic the theories are able to prove.  (Recall that the sentence $\operatorname{Con}(T),$ where T is a recursively presented theory, is itself a sentence of arithmetic.)

References:

Alan Turing, *Systems of Logic Based on Ordinals,* Ph.D. thesis (Princeton Univ.), 1938, which I believe can be found in: Andrew W. Appel, ed., *Alan Turing's Systems of Logic: The Princeton Thesis*, Princeton University Press, 2012.

S. Feferman, *Transfinite Recursive Progressions of Axiomatic Theories*, Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 27, No. 3 (Sept. 1962), pp. 259-316, URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2964649 in JSTOR.

S. Feferman and C. Spector, *Incompleteness Along Paths in Progressions of Theories*, Journal of Symbolic Logic, Vol. 27, No. 4 (Dec., 1962), pp. 383-390, URL: http://www.jstor.org/stable/2964544 in JSTOR.

Answer (score 4):

A slightly more formal way of describing it would be to say that $T_0=\textrm {ZFC}$, $T_{n+1}=T_n\cup \{\operatorname{Con}(T_n)\}$, while $T_\omega=\bigcup_{n\in \omega} T_n$ (which you called ${\sf N}$).

Naively you could think that since $T_\omega$ contains $\operatorname{Con}(T_n)$ for every $n$, it would imply that no finitely many statements in any $T_n$ are contradictory, and hence that $T_\omega$ itself is not contradictory, by compactness, which by incompleteness theorem would imply that $T_\omega$ is contradictory, and hence (by compactness) some $T_n$ is already contradictory.

The same reasoning can be performed if you take $T_0=\textrm{PA}$, and (if you believe in ${\bf N}$), the conclusion is absurd, since each $T_n$ is clearly a part of TA (and so consistent).

I am not a proof theorist, so I do not feel exactly certain, but I think the issue with the reasoning in the second paragraph is the subtlety of the statement of $\operatorname{Con}(T_n)$. You need to understand what it really says: it means that if you interpret it as a statement about *the true universe of sets*, then it says that $T_n$ has a set model.

But what we really get is that $T_{n+1}$ says about a model $M$ if $M\models T_{n+1}$ is that "$M$ satisfies $T_n$ and in addition, it thinks it has a model of $T_n$ inside". Similarly, when we have some $M\models T_\omega$, it just means that $M$ satisfies $\textrm{ZFC}$, and in addition, it thinks it has models of each $T_n$ inside.

The issue here is with the "thinks". It may very well be that $M$ is wrong about containing the model of some $T_n$ (for example, its membership relation might not at all be the true membership relation), in which case the dominoes fall. Again, one might argue that since $M$ thinks it has a model of each $T_n$, we can apply compactness (in $M$, since it satisfies ZFC!) to find a model of $T_\omega$ inside $M$ (or at least to make $M$ think it has one). But that will not work because to apply compactness, $M$ would need to be aware not only of a model of each of $T_n$ separately, but also of models for all *simultaneously*.

More precisely, even if we have $m_n\in M$ such that $M\models "m_n\models T_n"$, we cannot say that it implies that $M\models "(\forall n)\, m_n\models T_n"$; indeed, $M$ may not even know the true natural numbers, so it doesn't make much sense to quantify over them! And even if $M$ does know all the natural numbers, it may know more of them than just $\omega$, so even if for all $n$ we have $M\models "m_n\models T_n"$, it may have some nonstandard $n^*$ such that $M\models "m_{n^*}\not\models T_{n^*}"$, in which case actually $M\models \exists n\in {\omega} "m_n\not\models T_n"$ (as witnessed by $n^*$, which $M$ considers to be in $\omega$).

Comment: The problem is not with what $ \operatorname{Con}(T)$ means; it means what you probably think it means (that no contradiction can be derived from the formulas in $T).$ The actual issue is something different: although, for each $n,$ $T_\omega$ proves $\operatorname{Con}(T_n),$ $T_\omega$ does not prove the single sentence $(\forall n) \operatorname{Con}(T_n).$  That latter sentence is what you would need in order to apply the compactness theorem.