# How many layers of consistency can PA recognize?

Tags: logic, proof-theory

$\newcommand{\Cons}{\operatorname{Cons}}\newcommand{\PA}{\mathsf{PA}}$Assuming $\PA$ is consistent, we know that $\PA \nvdash \Cons(\PA)$ and $\PA + \Cons(\PA) \nvdash \Cons(\PA + \Cons(\PA))$, and so on.

Let $T_0 := \PA$ and $T_{\alpha^+} := T_\alpha + \Cons(T_\alpha)$ and $T_\beta := \bigcup_{\alpha < \beta} T_\alpha$.

What is the minimal ordinal $\alpha$ such that $T_\alpha$ cannot be written as a sentence in the language of Peano arithmetic?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, first of all it doesn't really make sense to talk about $T_\alpha$ for $\alpha$ an ordinal; instead we need to talk about [ordinal *notations*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O) (these are basically just "particularly nice" computable well-orderings of $\mathbb{N}$ - *specific copies* of ordinals rather than the more abstract ordinals themselves). Two notations for the same ordinal may wind up behaving quite differently in terms of the "iterated consistency extension" they yield - see e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2013089/28111).

That said, it turns out that there is a rather sharp answer to your question. Ordinal notations go up through the computable ordinals, that is, up to $\omega_1^{CK}$. Meanwhile, every *arithmetically definable* well ordering is in fact isomorphic to a computable one (indeed much more is true: "hyperarithmetic = computable" for ordinals, this is a theorem of Spector).

So briefly:

> We can iterate consistency principles along computable well-orderings (not computable *ordinals* per se) without trouble, but we can't even arithmetically refer to $\omega_1^{CK}$ or above.